# open form record with button

Tags: ms-access, button

I need to open a form (shipments) from a button on another form and have that opened form be on that "CustomerID"s record so you can easily add a new shipment to that customer. Any suggestions? I have tried using a macro to no avail but code eludes me. everything is linked via customerID under relationships.

I am using access 2007.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new button called btnOpenForm, and add this to the module:

```
Private Sub btnOpenForm_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_btnOpenForm_Click

    Dim stDocName As String
    Dim stLinkCriteria As String

    stDocName = "frmMyForm"
    stLinkCriteria = "[CustomerID] = '" & Me.CustomerID & "'"
    DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName, , , stLinkCriteria

Exit_btnOpenForm_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_btnOpenForm_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_btnOpenForm_Click

End Sub
```

The key here is the variable 'stLinkCriteria'.  You set it to include the field name ("CustomerID") and the value you want to filter by ("Me.CustomerID").  If either your table's field name or your textbox name are different, you'll have to edit those values appropriately.  Also, you'll have to change the value of 'stDocName' to whatever your form's name is as well.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the quick reply. I changed  stDocName = "frmMyForm"  to stDocName = "Form_Shipments" yet the button does not work (I also tried just Shipments)

Comment: It does not open the form.

Comment: Make sure the On Click event of the button is pointing to this sub.

Comment: Should that be in the drop down control? or the ellipsis?

Comment: I think it's in the dropdown.  You should just have to choose "[Event Procedures]" from the dropdown.  But if you click the elipsis it should take you right to the same code block.

Comment: It is not in the drop down, the code is definitely there. Is it an instance issue perhaps?

Comment: Then choose "[Event Procedures]" and click the elipsis.  That's **got** to be there or you'd never be able to add any code.  Once the VBA screen comes up, paste everything but the "Private Sub" and "End Sub" lines in it.

Comment: Upon running the code I have an error stating "Invalid use of me keyword"

Comment: How do you reference anything on your form then?  Do you have to explicitly state Forms!MyFormName.MyControlName?

Comment: No. I do not need to do that for macros or anything else to my knowledge.

Comment: I changed the order of the logic, the 'stlink' line now follows after the docmd line, this provides me with an "Object is required error" so something is not referenced right. I am trying to debug atm

Comment: Once you've done the command, there's no need for the stLink line.  You need that first, or it's not taken into consideration.  I'm thinking you might be missing some references, possibly the VBA for Applications one.

Comment: I have now accomplished this by simply removing the Private Sub btnOpenForm_Click() and keeping it under the button sub then specifying my form. marked as answer.